# Change number of columns render when render with Datatables

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I create a datatable with [DataTables](https://datatables.net).

```
$('table').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'excel', 'print',
    ],
    responsive: true
}
```

My table has 11 columns.

I want show 5 columns and when click on `+` button show other 6 columns.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html

https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

The above examples will show you how to both hide columns by default, and then show them later with an event.

Hide by default :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 2 ],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        },
        {
            "targets": [ 3 ],
            "visible": false
        }
    ]
} );
```

Make visible on click

```
$('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the column API object
    var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );

    // Toggle the visibility
    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
} );
```

Comment: I want use responsive button when I click on it then show other cloumn like responsive example

Comment: Have you looked at this link?
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/column-visibility.html

Comment: Yes, with this can create a button but I want show other 6 columns with green + button in this page

Comment: Somthing like change width of each columns to send other 6 columns on it

Answer (score 0):

I think this way is good for you.

Add this code to your datatables.css :

```
table.dataTable th, table.dataTable td {
  padding-right: 25px !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```